# How to to join a table onto itself, grouping the field being joined on?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that creates a record each time a post is created and another table that creates a record each time a post is favorited.

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `favorited_posts` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`post_id`)
)
```

The following query returns a result set that shows how many times a post has been favorited

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.title,
    COUNT(fp.post_id) as num_favorites
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN favorited_posts fp
ON fp.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE p.post_id BETWEEN 0 AND 10000
GROUP BY 1;

+-------------------+----------------+
| post_id  | title  |  num_favorites |
+-------------------+----------------+
| 1        | abc    |  15            |
| 2        | hello  |  0             |
| 3        | test   |  7             |
+----------+--------+----------------+
```

How can I change the query to create an ad-hoc column with a true/false, 0/1 value that represents whether a user has favorited a particular post?  It would produce a result set like this (The user has favorited post 2 and 3)

```
+-------------------+----------------+---------------+
| post_id  | title  |  num_favorites | has_favorited |
+-------------------+----------------+---------------+
| 1        | abc    |  15            | 0             |
| 2        | hello  |  0             | 1             |
| 3        | test   |  7             | 1             |
+----------+--------+----------------+---------------+
```

I can retrieve the posts a particular user has favorited with the query but do not know how to retrieve this information as part of a single query that captures the post_id, title and total number of favorites.

```
SELECT * FROM favorited_posts
WHERE user_id = 10;
```

Comment: You're using a nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. You really want `GROUP BY 1,2` here.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the second query in the left join:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.title, IF(COUNT(fp.post_id)>0, 'True', 'False') as user_favorite
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT post_id FROM favorited_posts
        WHERE user_id = 10
    ) fp ON fp.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE p.post_id BETWEEN 0 AND 10000
GROUP BY 1;
```

Also, you miss a foreign key in `favorited_posts` to the `user` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.post_id,
       p.title,
       COUNT(fp.post_id) as num_favorites,
       sum(case when fp.user_id = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as has_favorited
  FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN favorited_posts fp
    ON fp.post_id = p.post_id
 WHERE p.post_id BETWEEN 0 AND 10000
 GROUP BY p.post_id, p.title
```

This query is the same as what you have now except it shows a column that indicates whether or not the given user (specified in the case statement) has favorited the particular post on the given row.